# How can I sort pictures in a folder based on similarity?

Tags: file-management

I have many duplicate photos in a folder. How can I sort the pictures in a folder by similarity? i.e., sorting not based on the file name or date, but based on similarity of image?

Comment: Similarity of what? The image?

Comment: Is this question a duplicate? http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/6326/4892

Comment: This is an interesting - perhaps not even photography-related - question and I don't recall seeing a stand-along solution although this is done as part of many algorithms. modern video compression is all about finding similarity and encoding images in terms of contents from one or more reference frames.

Comment: Are these exact duplicates? (pixel per pixel)

Comment: yes these are exact duplicates pixel per pixel.... only the file name is different.

Comment: If they are exact dupes then what about sorting by filesize? Or have the extensions changed and different compression been applied?

Comment: I installed Picasa through wine.... It solved my search....

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to sort by picture similarity in most file browsers that I know of; and I have used many. It sounds like you need to look for a program that is designed to find duplicate pictures. There are many out there and what you use depends on your hardware/software setup. I have found that they are not 100% accurate so I usually use more than one program to find duplicates and then I still try and go through and see if I can find any. I use windows and have used auslogics duplicate file finder and anti-twin.

Answer (score 0):

Images can be grouped by similarity but can't be sorted.

Some advanced programs allows you to specify a similarity degree, and another ones treat as duplicates only 100% identical photos.

[Daminion](http://daminion.net) allows you to find 100% similar images (as you requested) but file names and metadata part of your images can be different.

PS. I work at Daminion Software.